# install WCF service in IIS (clients)

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, service, installation

I searched but couldn´t find a clear answear...

I want to install my WCF Service (IIS) on the Client side (the customers)
is there a easy way to do so?

thanks

ps. its C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx) it from Visual Studio by yourself or create Visual Studio [Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/996a3fxs%28VS.71%29.aspx) if you want your customer do this by himself.